# <Link> in Javascript / React-Router does not work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a details page for the product.
I have a page that shows all object(in http://localhost:3000/products/all)
and my details page location is http://localhost:3000/product/headphons120/12/ (for example)
and I use this code:

```
{products.map((product) => (
          <Link
            key={product.id}
            to={`product/${product.slug}/${product.id}/`}
            className="p-link"
          >
            <div className="product">
              <div className="cover">
                <img src={`http://localhost:5000${product.photo}`} />
              </div>
              <div className="p-inform">
                <span>{product.name}</span>
                <span>{product.price}</span>
                <span>{product.point}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
```

but in `all` page `product/${product.slug}/${product.id}/` addition to:
http://localhost:3000/products/all

and result: http://localhost:3000/products/product/T-shirt/9/

I want to have http://localhost:3000/product/T-shirt/9/

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think we're missing some code here, because product is sitting at the root of products. Do you have anything that references the products folder?

Comment: to={`product/${product.slug}/${product.id}/`} I guess if you add "/" in front of product and just passing string will do the work. like this to="/product/${product.slug}/${product.id}"

Comment: thank you its work i should use this ` to="/product/${product.slug}/${product.id}" `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever we are using the relative path in the Link component, we need to add / before URL.

```
<Link to="/product/${product.slug}/${product.id}"></Link>
```